# How can I request a original path without id after update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.1.5

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "services#index"  
  resources :apis, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :commons, path: "/self-care2/commonController" do
      collection do
         post :search, to: "commons#search"
      end
  end
end
```

Here is my create action of commons controller:

```
def create
  @api = Api.new(api_params)
  if @api.save
    flash[:info] = request.original_url + ".do?apiname=" + "#{@api.name}"
    redirect_to root_path
  else 
    @api.statuses.new
    render :new
  end
end
```

And here is my update action of commons controller:

```
def update
  @api = Api.find(params[:id])
  if @api.update(api_params)
    flash[:info] = request.original_url + ".do?apiname=" + "#{@api.name}"
    redirect_to root_path
  else 
    @api.statuses.new
    render :edit
  end
end
```

After I create a new record it will flash a url to me:

```
 http://localhost:3000/self-care2/commonController.do?apiname=loginCSP
```

And after I updated it I also got a flash :

```
 http://localhost:3000/self-care2/commonController/58.do?apiname=loginCSP
```

Is there any way that I can get rid off the object id which is "/58" after I update?

What I want it create and update both return same url to me.

Comment: Try `flash[:info] = commons_url + ".do?apiname=#{@api.name}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `request.original_url`, use a url helper

```
flash[:info] = commons_url + ".do?apiname=#{@api.name}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for the update function:

```
org_url = request.original_url
flash[:info] = org_url[0, org_url.rindex("/")] + ".do?apiname=" + "#{@api.name}"
```